# mysql outer join not showing null results

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have two tables that I am trying to complete a full outer join on.

```
availability
availability_id   availability_desc
1                 Monday Morning
2                 Monday Afternoon
3                 Monday Evening
etc

user_availability
user_id          availability_id
1                1
1                3
etc

SELECT * from availability a left outer join user_availability u 
on a.availability_id=u.availability_id;
```

gives the result:

```
availability_id; availability_desc;        id;     user_id;       availability_id
1;               Monday Morning;           1;      1;             1
1;               Monday Morning;           15;     2;             1
1;               Monday Morning;           40;     4;             1
1;               Monday Morning;           57;     5;             1
2;               Monday Afternoon;         2;      1;             2
3;               Monday Evening;           16;     2;             3
3;               Monday Evening;           42;     4;             3
```

A right outer join on the same tables results in:

```
availability_id     availability_desc   id  user_id availability_id
1                   Monday Morning      1   1        1
2                   Monday Afternoon    2   1        2
4                   Tuesday Morning     3   1        4
```

A union of the right and left outer join gives these results:

```
availability_id availability_desc   id  user_id availability_id
1               Monday Morning      1   1       1
1               Monday Morning      15  2       1
1               Monday Morning      40  4       1
1               Monday Morning      57  5       1
2               Monday Afternoon    2   1       2
2               Monday Afternoon    30  3       2
2               Monday Afternoon    41  4       2
3               Monday Evening      16  2       3
3               Monday Evening      42  4       3
```

I am not getting any null values returned when there is not a match in the other table. I am looking to generate results that look like this:

```
availability_desc     user_id
Monday Morning        1
Monday Afternoon      1
Monday Evening        (null)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So you want to show a record for each user for each availability whether they have a matching record or not?

Comment: Given your short sample data, I do get a row returned with a null user_id: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4be26/1

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Interestingly, I do not get the same using my actual table structure and data. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94713/1/0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a record for each user, for each availability, whether they have a matching record or not, this will do the trick.  This is assuming there is a table called `user` that has all of the users in the system.  Using the `CROSS JOIN` allows you to get each user record for each availability record.  Then joining both of those tables to the user_availability table will see if the user is available or not.

```
SELECT * 

FROM   availability a 

       cross join user u

       LEFT JOIN user_availability ua
       on u.user_id = ua.user_id
       AND a.availability_id = ua.availability_id
;
```

Here's a more readable version, plus a sqlfiddle.

```
SELECT availability_desc, 
       user_name, 
       CASE WHEN ua.user_id IS NULL THEN 'Not Available' ELSE 'Available' END AS availability

FROM   availability a 

       cross join user u

       LEFT JOIN user_availability ua
       on u.user_id = ua.user_id
       AND a.availability_id = ua.availability_id
;
```

sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/626489/4